# How to convert a "FlatButton" to "TextButton" in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, button, upgrade, flatbutton

I got following code:

```
      FlatButton.icon(
        minWidth: double.infinity,
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          vertical: kDefaultPadding,
        ),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
        color: kPrimaryColor,
        onPressed: () {},
        icon: WebsafeSvg.asset("assets/Icons/Edit.svg", width: 16),
        label: Text(
          "New message",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ).addNeumorphism(
        topShadowColor: Colors.white,
        bottomShadowColor: Color(0xFF234395).withOpacity(0.2),
      ),
```

It seems the `FlatButtun` is now deprecated and I must convert it to `TextButton` but when I try that, it gives me errors for `minWith` parameter. When I try to wrap it with `ConstrainedBox` I get other errors for `padding` shape, etc.

I don't know how make this old code work as expected before?

Comment: I think you'll have to use `TextButton.icon` and then wrap it with the correct corresponding widgets, such as `Padding`/`SizedBox`. Regarding styling, you can use the `style` parameter.

Comment: Here the changes are explained https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons. Can you show us the TextButton code that you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've commented, you can't just "convert" a `FlatButton.icon` to a `TextButton.icon`. The changes in the buttons are [breaking changes](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons) made to Flutter:

> A new set of basic material button widgets and themes have been added
> to Flutter. The original classes have been deprecated and will
> eventually be removed. The overall goal is to make buttons more
> flexible, and easier to configure via constructor parameters or
> themes.

So, to solve your problem, you'll have to compose your own widgets to get close to `FlatButton.icon`.

For your example, you can use the `Padding` widget for padding, and `SizedBox` for the width. for rounded corners, you can use the `style` property.

Your button code can look something like this using `TextButton.icon`:

```dart
SizedBox(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          vertical: 10,
        ),
        child: TextButton.icon(
          //rounded corners
          style: ButtonStyle(
            shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
              RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
              ),
            ),
          ),

          onPressed: () {},
          icon: WebsafeSvg.asset("assets/Icons/Edit.svg", width: 16),
          label: Text(
            "New message",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but it still says: `The named parameter 'child' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'child'.` in this line of the code `child: TextButton.icon(`